# AngularJS array.push ng:repeat not updating

Tags: angularjs

I have a create function in a service which is responsible for taking input data, turning it into a resource, doing a save and inserting it into a local cache.

```
create = (data, success, error) ->
    throw new Error("Unable to create new user, no company id exists") unless $resource_companies.id()

    # create the resource
    new_model = new resource(data)

    # manually add the company id into the payload (TODO: company id should be inferred from the URL)
    new_model.company_id = $resource_companies.id()

    # do the save and callbacks
    new_model.$save( () ->
        list.push(new_model)
        success.call(@) if success?
    , error)
```

My problem is that an ng:repeat that watches the list variable is not getting updated. As far as I can tell this is not occurring outside on AngularJS so it does not require a $scope.$apply() to keep it up to date (indeed, if I try to trigger a digest, I get a digest already in progress error)

What's doubly weird, is I have this exact same pattern used elsewhere without issue.

The code used by my controller to access the list array is (this is in the service)

```
# refreshes the users in the system
refresh = (cb) -> list = resource.query( () -> cb.call(@) if cb? )
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.users = $resource_users.refresh()
```

Comment: I added some debugging around this. I can see that a digest is getting called after the array.push occurs, but in the $scope.users which should be pointing to a reference of the array, still reports the old items in the array.

It's like somehow the array reference is not being passed correctly.

Comment: $scope.users is pointing to a reference in the array? How so?

Comment: $scope.users is point to the array variable "list" in the service through the refresh function. list is scoped in the service so that both the refresh and the create methods can reach it.

Comment: I've created a gist here wich a stripped back version of the controller / service: https://gist.github.com/Rodeoclash/5762240

Comment: If the $watch is watching the actual "list" variable, that won't trigger anything. If it's watching $scope.users, that will trigger anytime the $scope.users is updated. I'd have to see the rest of the controller to get a sense of what's going on.

Comment: The ng:repeat is watching the $scope.users in the controller. The rest of the controller is related to click items for editing users etc but do not directly affect the $scope.users, only the service which interacts with it.

Comment: Are you expecting the service to automatically update the controller $scope? Because the only way a service can update a controller is with event emitters and listeners. Otherwise there needs to be something happening in the controller that calls the service and updates the item.

Comment: I assume $scope.users is an object? $watch does not work directly with objects. This is how I would watch this

var users;
$scope.$watch(function() {
 return JSON.stringify($scope.users);
},function(_users) {
 users = JSON.parse(_users);
 if(typeof users !== 'undefined') {
  //watch stuff here
 } 
});

Comment: What s cb? Your refresh method seems to not nothing without it. Also can you translate this to a non-coffee version? The code is hard to read.

Comment: You could try `$scope.$watchCollection` or `$scope.$watch(.., .., true)` where the `true` tells it to examine the actual contents of the property being watched.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what was causing this issue and some refactoring along the way seemed to have solved it. I'm going to chalk it up to me not correctly understanding object references with Angular. Thanks for the comments everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are assigning a new reference. Angular is watching the old reference, and it never changes. Here is the where the reference is replaced:

```
list = resource.query( /* ... */ )
```

If, instead, you make the list a property of an object, angular's ng-repeat watch should be able to observe the change in the `list` property of the `data` object:

```
data.list = resource.query( /* ... */ )
```